# Switch audio outputs without using the GUI dialog for PulseAudio

Tags: pulseaudio, dialog

I'm using Precise (development version), which means I'm very much expecting to see bugs. However, this time, it's fairly important that I find a workaround quickly – and it is a general question.

The problem: When I open Sound Settings from the audio menu or from Gnome Control Center, it simply closes with no question of bug reports. I am too drunk to look at stack traces, and I really want to listen to Nellie McKay – loudly. Now, I have a USB audio device that's connected to my speakers. It has no headphone output. I would like to change the output device to my internal audio source – which does have headphone output – so that I can listen to music without bothering the neighbors. For some reason or other, I can't open the audio dialog.

Since PulseAudio seems to be working properly, I need a CLI-way to change the audio device that's used for output for PulseAudio sources.

If someone can tell me how to do this, I'd be very happy. If I get the explanation before I'm evicted for public disturbance, I'll consider that a bonus. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find your solution here:

[Audio output device, fast switch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4055/audio-output-device-fast-switch/89089#89089)

or here:

[How to change pulseaudio sink with  "pacmd set-default-sink" during playback?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71863/how-to-change-pulseaudio-sink-with-pacmd-set-default-sink-during-playback/72076#72076)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way that does not use the Control center is to use the [sound switcher indicator](http://yktoo.com/en/software/indicatorSoundSwitcher) ([webup8 article](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/sound-switcher-ubuntu-indicator.html)).

Comment: The OP requested a non-gui solution. The linked Sound Switcher Indicator is a gui element