# How to force audio from speakers and headphone

Tags: sound, headphones

Im looking to install ubuntu on my laptop, problem is that I damaged the headphone socket and it thinks there is always headphones plugged in. I know in windows I can force audio to play from both the speakers and the headphones at the same time.

Is this possible in ubuntu/linux ?

Thanks!

Comment: I want it too... because I want playback on all speaker to get louder

Answer (score 2):

Install **pavucontrol** from the following [link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/).

Now open the app using the follwing cmd in terminal :

```
pavucontrol
```

Now in the **Playback** tab, change the output to speakers--->

[image]

Comment: And after a reboot?

Comment: I'll check.. we can make a script if necessary, right ?

Comment: It didn't change and looking for an insight for scripting I found [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/103443/438174). It's not necessary but maybe helpful for switching using terminal...

Comment: Hi araghuteja, Thanks for your reply. I asked this over a year ago and have yet to find a solution. Will your suggestion output audio from both the headphone jack and the speakers at the same time?

Comment: Yes, output comes from both. But you'll have to do something more-   Open **AlsaMixer**  with the following cmd:  `alsamixer`.

Use right arrow key to move to speakers and increase its level to maximum. Set **Auto-Mute** to disabled.  Now, open **pavucontrol** and go to **Output Devices** --> change the **Port**  to **Speakers (unavailable)**.  Now the volume comes from both speakers and headphones together... I'll give  a screen-shot if necessary.

Comment: @L337BEAN Did you test my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

### **My Solution** *(not recommended)*

Step 1: remove completely PulseAudio by `sudo apt-get autoremove pulseaudio`

Step 2: Install AlsaMixer by `sudo apt-get install gnome-alsamixer`

Step 2: Config with AlsaMixer by run `alsamixer`. Press left/right arrow to choose device, change volume, disabled auto-mute,... press [ESC] to quit.

### RISK

You will lost some utility provides by PulseAudio, example: disappear Volume Tray, lost Hotkey Fn+(volume) on keyboard,...

### NO-TESTED

Just remove PulseAudio, not completely remove: `sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio`, maybe help keep sound utility, hotkey... I read somewhere, PulseAudio output sound quality better and smaller latency than default audio server...

### RECOVERY

If you want sound system goes back. Open Ubuntu Software Center, click on History to see what are package removes before? Open Sysnaptic Package Manager, search there packages then Install them.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was simply to select the device manually:

1. Open Sound settings (you can get there from the volume control
   widget or System Settings)
2. Under the default Output tab, under
   Device, click "Analog Output Built-in Audio"

Yes, you'll need to manually set the device you want to use each time, but for me two seconds doing that is better than another several days of searching and at best, it seems, setting output permanently (changing only with a reboot).  I've not seen any fix for the root problem of flaky jack detection.  I described the [symptoms in my case in greater detail here](http://data.agaric.com/laptop-inconsistently-detecting-and-using-external-audio-heaphone-jack-%E2%80%94-workaround).